# Uniform distribution of binary values in Matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

I have a requirement for the generation of a given number N of vectors of given size each consistent of a uniform distribution of 0s and 1s.

This is what I am doing at the moment, but I noticed that the distribution is strongly peaked at half 1s and half 0s, which is no good for what I am doing:

```
a = randint(1, sizeOfVector, [0 1]);
```

The [`unifrnd` function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/unifrnd.html) looks promising for what I need, but I can't manage to understand how to output a binary vector of that size.

Is it the case that I can use the `unifrnd` function (and if so how would be appreciated!) or can is there any other more convenient way to obtain such a set of vectors?

Any help appreciated!

**Note 1**: just to be sure - here's what the requirement actually says:

> randomly choose N vectors of given size that are
> uniformly distributed over [0;1]

**Note 2**: I am generating initial configurations for Cellular Automata, that's why I can have only binary values [0;1].

Comment: Are you sure that by `[0; 1]` they don't mean the *interval* of all real numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: Also, if you draw `n` numbers uniformly from the set `{0, 1}` it is to be expected that about half of them are 0, half of them are 1. That is the idea of a uniform distribution, after all.

Comment: I am sure - I am generating initial configurations for cellular automata and there's only 2 states: ON/OFF [0, 1]

Comment: @Thomas interesting, so are you saying I already have a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate 1 random vector with elements from {0, 1}:

```
unidrnd(2,sizeOfVector,1)-1
```

The other variants are similar.

Comment: +1 - thanks! seems to work - but I am having troubles interpreting the expression, could you expand and also explain the difference between what you propose and what I currently have?

Comment: @John: `unidrnd` = Discrete uniform random numbers. `unidrnd(N,m,n)` generates an m*n matrix with random numbers in the range {1,2,...,N}. The `-1` is to put the result back to {0,1,...,N-1}. See http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/unidrnd.html.

Comment: ok tnx a lot, that explains the use of unidrnd - still trying to understand how that's different from what I have.

Comment: just to clarify my previous comment - what's the difference between using randint(1, 5, [0 1]) and unidrnd(2,1,5)-1 ?

Comment: @John: I don't know on MATLAB, but on Octave 3.0.3 only `unidrnd` exists, and `randint`/`randi` not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get uniformly distributed 0's and 1's, you want to use [randi](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html). However, from the requirement, I'd think that the vectors can have real values, for which you'd use [rand](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/randi.html)

```
%# create a such that each row contains a vector

a = randi(1,N,sizeOfVector); %# for uniformly distributed 0's and 1's

%# if you want, say, 60% 1's and 40% 0's, use rand and threshold
a = rand(N,sizeOfVector) > 0.4; %# maybe you need to call double(a) if you don't want logical output

%# if you want a random number of 1's and 0's, use
a = rand(N,sizeOfVector) > rand(1);
```

Comment: thanks but I can only have 0s or 1s as explained in the question - also isn't randi the same as randint? only difference is randint is deprecated I think :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, randi is the 'modern' version of randint.

Also, yes, uniform distribution means all possible values are chosen with equal frequency.